# Sending User Credential to facebook remotely

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does Anyone know how to send the Login username and password to facebook from java code remotely without going to browser ... i want to create a desktop application which uses facebook data to update the status

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not support login through third party applications.
You have to use facebook open auth to authenticate an user.